# A non well formed numeric value encountered error

Tags: php

This code used to work when the script takes about 15 mins to run, the script now takes longer to run so I'm getting this error

PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in line 151

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
//Removed script
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
$time = number_format($time,0);
$time = gmdate("H:i:s",$time);   //LINE 151

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO updater(duration) VALUES(?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $time);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using `number_format()`, which adds thousands separator commas if a value if > 1000.... `1,000` is a decidedly non-well formatted numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"non-well formed numeric value". You're passing a **STRING** in to `gmdate()`, which expects an integer timstamp.

You probably want

```
$time = $time_end - $time_start
$formatted = gmdate('H:i:s', (int)$time);
...
$stmt->bind_param('s', $formatted);
```

instead. Note the `(int)`, since your timestart/end values are in floating point values, and date/gmdate expect time in seconds. PHP would convert for you, but I like making it explicit...

Comment: Any reason why the code used to work and now it doesn't?

Comment: Probably PHP got upgraded, or a system-wide setting got changed. number_format() has ALWAYS returned a string, so you should ALWAYS have gotten the warning.